# What is the best practice when it comes to dispose image object in c#?

Tags: c#

I have following two pieces of code First one is not explicitly disposing Image object while second one is disposing it correctly. Please suggest which one to use in production code.

```
private bool SavePatientChartImage(byte[] ImageBytes, string ImageFilePath, string IMAGE_NAME, int rotationAngle)
    {
        bool success = false;
        System.Drawing.Image newImage;
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ImageBytes))
            {
                newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                switch (rotationAngle)
                {
                    case 90:
                        newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                        break;
                    case 180:
                        newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                        break;
                    case 270:
                        newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                        break;
                    default:
                        newImage = newImage;
                        break;
                }
                newImage.Save(Path.Combine(ImageFilePath, IMAGE_NAME));
                success = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

and

```
private bool SavePatientChartImage(byte[] ImageBytes, string ImageFilePath, string IMAGE_NAME, int rotationAngle)
    {
        bool success = false;
        System.Drawing.Image newImage;
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ImageBytes))
            {
                using(newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream))
                {
                switch (rotationAngle)
                {
                    case 90:
                        newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                        break;
                    case 180:
                        newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                        break;
                    case 270:
                        newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                        break;
                    default:
                        newImage = newImage;
                        break;
                }
                newImage.Save(Path.Combine(ImageFilePath, IMAGE_NAME));
                success = true;
              }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Which one to follow religiously. Please suggest

Comment: Rarely does anybody follow any advice religiously in programming.  Every feature in a programming language was added for some use case, so whenever you reach that use case (it may be rare - an example would be the C goto) you should make use of the feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2809026/555547 may be helpful. Personally, I would just use the second because it's not that hard, and it should dispose of resources properly when complete, but I'm no expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always dispose the disposable instances somewhere. So take the latter.

You could make it a bit more readable:

```
       using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ImageBytes))
       using(var newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream))
       {
         // ...
```

Note: It doesn't make sense to have the variable declared outside the using statement. You shouldn't use it outside.