# Dispose of an Image Held as a Property on a Class

Tags: c#

If I have a class like

```
public class Foo 
{
   private Image image;
   ....
   ....
}
```

should I create destructor and call Dispose there to free the image's memory or the DC will do it automatically.

Comment: You *should* [read](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/413887/Understanding-and-Implementing-IDisposable-Interfa) about C# more.

Comment: This link is probably helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808753/right-way-to-dispose-image-bitmap-and-picturebox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as proposed by Microsoft. The first DO in the article states: implement the Basic Dispose Pattern on types containing instances of disposable types. See the Basic Dispose Pattern section for details on the basic pattern.

Since Image is a disposable type you should implement IDisposable on the wrapping class.

I wouldn't bother with destructors, since it might take a while before the object gets destructed, while with Dispose you maintain control.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement IDisposable:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private Image image;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            image.Dispose();
            image = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then Usage:

```
using(var f = new Foo())
{

} // disposed automatically
```

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.
>   The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a
>   managed object when that object is no longer used. However, it is not
>   possible to predict when garbage collection will occur. Furthermore,
>   the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged resources such as
>   window handles, or open files and streams.